# Assembly - can't set breakpoint using lldb for assembled files on macOS

Tags: assembly, nasm, lldb

I'm learning assembly language on a x86_64 Macbook with macOS 10.14. The nasm version is 2.14, and the lldb version is 11.38.2.

My source code is very simple:

```
SECTION .data


EatMsg: db "Hello World", 0x0a
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg

SECTION .bss

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:
    nop
    mov rax,0x2000004
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,EatMsg
    mov rdx,EatLen
    syscall

    mov rax,0x2000001
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

I assemble this file using

```
nasm -f macho64 -F dwarf helloworld.asm
ld -e _start -no_pie -o helloworld helloworld.o -lSystem
```

But when I using lldb:

```
lldb helloworld
(lldb)b helloworld.asm:16
```

It says:

```
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

I have seen [Unable to set breakpoints lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803989/assembly-unable-to-set-breakpoints-lldb) and [Is it possible to debug x64 assembly on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493487/is-it-possible-to-debug-x64-assembly-on-mac-os), and I tried those answers(such as `-g`), but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you tried `nasm -f macho64 -F dwarf -g helloworld.asm`?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters to lldb (I don't have OS/X handy today) but did you try `lldb ./helloworld` rather than `lldb helloworld`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried both but to no avial